# Apache SOLR indexing stop working

Tags: 7, search

solr indexing has suddenly stop working.

Here is all the detail which i got from system admin

while running cron we are getting message during run cron.php through command

PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  REMOTE_ADDR in /var/www/XXXXXXX/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1670
PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

where should i look first and what are the possibility for apache solr indexing to stop suddenly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The not to good solution was, deleted all the index of apache solr and tried with the fresh indexing and all of sudden all thing work well.

Comment: I think this is actually a good solution, sure could be better especially if you have to reindex a lot of items. But this would be an easy to try and fix for getting the production site back online. I think most in most cases the indexing stopped working the index got corrupted. reindexing would then be the best option. +1